# How to pass credentials through header on redirect in asp.net mvc

Tags: access-token

When you are redirection from one page to another that time you can pass the value from header or save it in browser cache.

Following code is for how to send header value from mvc site to another site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In MVC change default Return Type "Action Result" to "Void"
- Make Action HTTPPOST.

  [HttpPost]
  public void About()
  {
      string appURL = "http://google.co.in";
      Response.AppendHeader("Username", "user123");
      Response.AppendHeader("Password", "password");
      Response.Status = "301 Moved permanently";
      Response.AppendHeader("Location", appURL);
      Response.End();
  }

Comment: i dont miss mvc